# How can I change home screen in the Apache HUE?

Tags: django, hue

After installing and configuring the Apache HUE, I try to change home screen in the Apache HUE. Is it right way to change home screen in the Apache HUE manually?
Thank you for your help in advance.

> /usr/local/hue/

Answer (score 0):

In the very latest Hue 4, you can select the landing Editor or Dashboard (e.g. Hive, Impala, Pig, Search etc...). Previously you would land on the homepage all the time.

Comment: My Hue version is Hue™ 3.12.0. I want to change home screen, not about  screen.

Answer (score 0):

There are some changes in the code. Please check the below file.

## /usr/local/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/views.py

`def index(request):
  if request.user.is_superuser and request.COOKIES.get('hueLandingPage') != 'home' and not IS_HUE_4.get():
    return home2(request)
  else:
    if IS_HUE_4.get():
      return responsive(request)
    elif USE_NEW_EDITOR.get():
      return home2(request)
    else:
      return home(request)`